# Playing a second SoundEffect after the first one has finished

Tags: c#, audio

In my app I'm using SoundEffect to play some sounds. I want to know if there's a way of knowing when a SoundEffect finished its run so a second one will start right after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the old question, but i had to do the same thing today, i tried the method based on duration but finally stopped with own solution which seems the simplest for me:

1) create static helper class let's say 'SoundsManager' as in lysergic-acid's answer.

2) create a Queue of SoundsEffectInstanses and play first of them ("_sheduledSounds" in code below).

3) Update class with each game loop and check if soundinstance is stopped:

```
public static void Update()
        {
            if (_sheduledSounds != null && _sheduledSounds.Count > 1)
            {
                if (_sheduledSounds.Peek().State == SoundState.Stopped)
                {
                    _sheduledSounds.Dequeue();
                    _sheduledSounds.Peek().Play();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

This scenario is not supported out of the box by XNA as far as i know.

The SoundEffect class exposes a *Duration* property that you might use to achieve what you're after.

Build some "SoundManager" class (basically a simple scheduler), that will do all the fancy coordination of sounds playback.

This class will hit off a SoundEffect playback, scheduling the next one to occur exactly after *Duration* had elapsed.

Answer (score 0):

Set this 
BufferDescription.GlobalFocus flag = True;

This will tell a SoundEffect finished its run.

Comment: I don't believe this is supported in XNA.